# Transfrom translate - как влияет на отрисовку и производительность в браузере

Tags: css, css3

Как влияет на отрисовку в браузере элемент с `transform: translate()`?
То есть, как изменилась бы скорость отрисовки если бы я позиционировал элемент через `top`, `left` и т. д.; можно ли это как то измерить через devtools?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/163645/

Comment: не совсем то, имелось ввиду не анимация а именно расположение

Comment: расположение при загрузке

Answer (score 1):

Если вы будете сдвигать элемент при помощи `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`, то при каждом изменении на 1 пиксель блок будет перерисовываться заново — не тяжело догадаться, что это не лучшее решение с точки зрения производительности. Если же вы будете сдвигать элемент при помощи `transform`, то для элемента будет использовано GPU-ускорение, для него будет создан отдельный слой, перерисовка блока при движении не будет происходить.

Для `transform` возможно субпиксельное движение: при анимировании свойств `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` движение будет дискретным, а при использовании `transform` — непрерывным.

Отследить разницу можно в devtools при помощи Paint Flashing, найти его можно так: http://prntscr.com/f0oaoh.

Comment: GPU если я не ошибаюсь включается когда идет 3d трансформация или используется will-change https://dev.opera.com/articles/ru/css-will-change-property/ - при 2d трансформациях никаких GPU-ускорение нет, однако элемент все равно плавнее двигается но вопрос был в другом.
А не спрашиваю про анимацию, я спрашиваю про верстку
Элемент я размещаю при помощи left и right или
Элемент я размещаю при помощи transform translate
При начальной отрисовке какой способ дает большую нагрузку

Comment: По поводу GPU-ускорения вы правы, этот момент я не описал детально, потому что сам всегда делаю через `translate3d()`. Если вам необходимо использовать смещение элемента один раз в самом начале, то разницы никакой нет — макет рассчитывается до рендера и не важно какие свойства использованы для смещения.

Comment: Если вам интересны все подробности рендера страницы и что влияет на этот процесс, то рекомендую вам ознакомиться с циклом Rendering performance https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/.